# Serve up a Java Applet with Laravel

Tags: java, php, laravel-4, applet

I'm trying to wrap my mind around how to deploy a Java applet in my Laravel app.

To start with I'm just going to keep it simple and use the applet tag in a view:

```
<applet code="OHLib.class" width=0 height=0 />
```

(The applet contains just helper functions ... no UI, so I set width and height to 0. Will that work?)

When the browser requests that class from my web site, how to I serve it up?  Do I define a route?  I would like the java class to be located at `www.mydomain.com/java/OHLib.class`.

Comment: Could you not just put the `.class` file in the `public/` directory (e.g. `public/java/OHLib.class`)?

Comment: @Whymarrh. Of course!  For some reason I thought everything went to the web app.  I had forgotten about the rewrite rule in .htaccess that only sends requests to the web app for URIs that don't exist.  I guess if you want to write that up as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's all good, it might be better for you to write up a description of what ended up working for you (where you put the `.class` file and what the final markup for the applet looked like) and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Deploy An Applet

Applets are deployed onto a web page via [certain tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html), which vary by browser, so the best thing to do is use a script provided by Oracle to inject the correct tag for you.  I put the following code in a `View` so as to appear within the `<body>` tag.  (It won't work in the `<head>` section.)

```
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script> 
<script>
    var attributes = { 
        id:'ohApplet',
        code:'OHLib',
        codebase: 'java',
        archive: 'OHLib.jar',   
        width:1, 
        height:1,
    } ;
    var parameters = { 
        jnlp_href: 'OHLib.jnlp',
        classloader_cache: 'false',
    } ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

This will cause the browser to load `OHLib.jar` from the `java` folder.  If the `.jar` file is in the same folder as the HTML document, you can skip the `codebase` attribute.  See [Deploying a Java Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html).

### Serve An Applet

When the browser parses the injected tag, it will then make a request to the server for the Java applet, based on the 'archive' and 'codebase' attributes.  So in my case I created a folder called 'java' under the Public folder, and placed the .jar file in there.   Remember that your web app only gets invoked for URIs that don't exist on the server file system.